# Print an element from a sorted array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell, unix

I wrote a program to sort an array and print the element where the unsorted array and sorted array matches. In theory, this should work, but it isn't. All the elements in the sorted array for some reason combine it all and output an array element of 1.

```
#!/bin/bash

arr=(6 2 15 90 9 1 4 30 1 3)

function sort(){
    local array=($@) max=$(($# - 1))
    while ((max > 0))
    do
        local i=0
        while ((i < max)); do
            if [ ${array[$i]} \> ${array[$((i + 1))]} ]
            then
                local t=${array[$i]}
                array[$i]=${array[$((i + 1))]}
                array[$((i + 1))]=$t
            fi
            ((i++))
        done
        ((max--))
    done
    echo ${array[@]}
}

arr_sort=($(sort ${arr[@]}))

for ((j=0; j<(( ${#arr[@]} -1 )); j++)); do
     for ((k=0; k<(( ${#arr[@]} -1 )); k++)); do
     if (( ${arr[j]:-0} == ${arr_sort[k]:-0} )); then
          echo ${arr[j]}
          break
     fi
done
```

Comment: `but it isn't` how do you know that? Do you get any errors? Why `break` on the first match? `Is something wrong?` Is there something wrong with the code you presented? Does something "not work" in it? What does "not work"? How does it "not work"? In general, what is the reason you are posting on this forum?

Comment: Is this a school assignment where you have to implement a sort function in bash? If not, it is not necessary to reinvent the wheel. You can sort your array with `arr_sort=( $(echo ${arr[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort) )`, without having to write a `function sort()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

arr=(6 2 15 90 9 1 4 30 1 3)
arr_sort=( $(echo ${arr[@]} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -n) )

for ((j=0; j<${#arr[@]}; j++)); do
     if (( ${arr[i]} == ${arr_sort[i]} )); then
       echo "Match ${arr[j]} at position $j (starting from 0)"
     fi
done
```

Since there are no matches between the unsorted array

```
 6  2 15 90  9  1  4 30  1  3
```

and the sorted one

```
 1  1  2  3  4  6  9 15 30 90
```

in the example you gave, you will have no output.